# C++0x (C++11) as functional language?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

i'm wondering if C++0x (C++11) (with lambdas and perfect forwarding) is (a superset of) a functional language.
is there any feature of functional languages, that C++ doesn't have?

Comment: Garbage collection?

Comment: if anybody has a list of functional languages features pls post them too

Comment: Most languages that I am aware of feature a functional subset (even C) -- that is, you can write your programs so that they never modify state, like a pure functional language (e.g., Haskell), so you will have to be more specific.

Comment: @Pascal if you never use `new` or `malloc` you have stack-based cleanup. This gives you two scopes: global and local. About what most functional languages have

Comment: @Emery: there's more to functional programming than immutable data and pure functions, eg higher-order functions, lexical closures, algebraic datatypes, lazy evaluation, ...

Comment: @KitsuneYMG If "scope" and "lifespan" were the same concepts, then yes, most functional languages would have only stack-based cleanup just like C++ without new. Unfortunately "scope" and "lifespan" are not nearly the same thing.

Comment: Stupid functional languages! They do not even have "new"!

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: @Christoph - Untyped lambda calculus is indisputably functional. The question is what the poster meant -- i.e., he didn't actually say "Haskell". C++0x *does* contain closures, and you can get everything you describe in current C++: see http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~yannis/fc++/

Comment: @JaredPar: please undelete your answer.  Don't let yourself get dragged down by commenters who didn't understand what you meant by "pattern matching".  (Although you might use the term "list comprehensions" to make it a little clearer that you aren't talking about regex)

Comment: @Gman - I don't know either, so I removed the tag. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The functional programming paradigm models computation as a relation between sets, and is thus inherently declarative. However, in practice, we often think of functions as imperative, ie you put in an input value and get out an output value, same as with a procedure. From this point of view, the characteristic property of a function is that it has no side-effects. Because of ambiguity of the terms, we call such a function *pure*, and a language which only has pure functions would be a *purely functional* language.

However, not all functional languages are pure: A *functional language* is a language with syntax and semantics which allows the programmer to use the functional paradigm efficiently. Some of the concepts which make using the paradigm feasible include - among others - lambda expressions with lexical closure, higher-order functions, variant types and pattern matching, lazy evaluation, type-inference (in case of statically-typed languages).

This is by no means an authorative list, and a language can very well be functional without providing all or even most of them, but if a language does - ie makes them usable without having to jump through major hoops - their presence is a strong indicator that the language should be considered functional.

I don't know enough about Boost to decide whether or not C++03 + Boost is a viable functional language, but C++0x definitely makes C++ *more* functional, perhaps even pushing it over the subjective boundary of the realm of functional languages.

As an aside, the same considerations apply to other programming paradigms: C++ is also not a purely object-oriented language (indeed, it's very hard - perhaps even theoretically impossible - to design a language which is both purely functional and purely object-oriented), and most features one commonly associates with OO-languages (classes, inheritance, encapsulation) are actually in no way authorative as well...

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553536/confused-is-oo-inherently-imperative-or-is-is-it-multi-paradigm/4861769#4861769

Answer (score 5):

Check out the list of [Functional Programming Languages](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?FunctionalProgramming) definitions and discussion on the C2 wiki.

Some of the most common (and least disputed features) are:

- First class functions - `function` class represents first class functions.
- Higher Order Functions - Can be emulated with function objects.
- Lexical Closures - Can be emulated with classes.
- Single Assignment - More of a convention.  You can do this by declaring all variables `const`.
- Lazy Evaluation - Can be achieved with TMP
- **Garbage Collection** - still missing.  Pretty much necessary in a functional language, since lifetime and scope are *not* the same, as @Pascal pointed out in the comments above.
- Type Inference - `auto`
- Tail Call Optimization - Not strictly necessary for a functional language, but compiler dependent in C++.

Comment: The C++0x standard allows for garbage collected implementations.

Comment: If you have to emulate just about everything, it's not a functional language — it's emulating one.

Comment: Lambda syntax provides a nice syntactic sugar to get lexical closures, it's not as bad as the word "emulate" suggests.  Lazy evaluation is gotten by passing a functor, which is also made easier with lambda syntax.

Comment: Tail call optimization is /really hard/ when C++'s RAII support comes into play. :(

Comment: Somewhat unrelated question, but would that suggest Python is a functional language?

Comment: The idea here is that there is no definitive list of features that make a language "functional".  Both C++ and Python have features that may be described as functional, and features that may be described as object-oriented, and features that may be described as procedural.  They are both multi-paradigm languages, and that may be the best way to describe them.

Comment: Let us not forget that "functional" is a programming style, not a language type. "Functional language" is a shorthand for "a language which allows to conveniently program functionally".